# Gmail not sending third party cookies

Tags: email, servlets, cookies, tracking

I'm writing an app in Java to know Email open notifications

Assume our servlet address :  **http://abc123.com/emailopen**

We are setting couple of cookies whenever user opens our website (http://abc123.com)

**Email open tracking**

I sent a Gmail to our customer , In the mail content I put the following line

**img src="http://abc123.com/emailopen" alt="Smiley face" height="1" width="1"**

So whenever customer opens this mail , we are getting servlet call successfully , because img src is pointing to our server.

**Now coming to the problem**

but the problem is when we got a call to our servlet, we are not getting cookies of our site, cookies getting null why??

This is happening only for Gmail, for Yahoo it's working fine.

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: You should add your code snippet for above tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique image name containing that customer's Id in the filename.  In other words, send

**img src="http://abc123.com/emailopen/id54321.jpg" height="1" width="1"**

Then when your server gets a hit on anything in /emailopen starting with id and ending in .jpg, you extract the id and flag the customer's record.

The downside of course is that you have to generate and send a unique email for each customer instead the same one to everyone.

Still not a 100% solution though, gmail and others have the option to not automatically open images unless the user consents.  And somewhere I read that now gmail is retrieving images even before the user opens the message, but I'm not sure if they backed off on that since they got a lot of flak about it.  It would be pretty easy to test.